# splitActionBarWhenNarrow not working for landscape android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using actionbar that has to split on landscape mode. When the device is in portrait it splits but when its on landscape it doesn't. I have enough items so that the actionbar is narrow even for the landscape view. Cannot we have actionbar at top and bottom during landscape? Please help.

Following is my mainactivity manifest

```
  <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.actionbar.MainActivity"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```